# What happens if after calling pthread_cond_wait(), another thread acquires the mutex that was locked and then phread_cond_broadcast is called?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

So let's say in one thread, you call `pthread_cond_wait()`. After that is called, the mutex of that thread is unlocked and now the thread is locked on the conditional variable. Now let's say another thread gains access to that lock. What will happen then after `pthread_cond_broadcast` is called? Does the other thread that gained control of the mutex after the wait call, lose control of the mutex? What happens exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Threads contend for the mutex normally. Nothing special happens. You can think of `pthread_cond_wait` as:

1. Atomically unlock the mutex and block on the condition variable.
2. Attempt to re-acquire the mutex normally.
3. Return.

Answer (score 0):

[`pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &m)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) waits for two events; signaling to condition variable `cv` and re-acquisition lock of mutex `m`.

In following code snippet,

```
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void producer_thread() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);         // p1
    // modify some_cond             // p2
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);    // p3
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);       // p4
}
void consumer_thread() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);         // c1
    while (!some_cond)              // c2
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &m); // c3
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);       // c4
}
```

Here is one possibly execution.

- c1: acquire lock
- c2: some_cond isn't satisfied
- c3: release lock and wait for signaling
- p1: acquire lock
- p2: satisfy some_cond
- p3: signal(broadcast) to threads wait on cv
- c3: **wake up by signaled cv, try to re-acquire lock, but block again.**
- p4: release lock
- c3: success to re-acquire lock.
- c2: some_cond is satisfied and exit while loop.
- c4: release lock